# subclassing Python's datetime.time

Tags: python, python-2.7

For whatever reason, I want to subclass datetime.time so that the subclass can be initialized by another datetime.time object. This sadly doesn't work:

```
class MyTime(datetime.time):
    def __init__(self, t):
        super().__init__(t.hour, t.minute, t.second, t.microsecond)

>>> t=datetime.time(10,20,30,400000)
>>> MyTime(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

obviously I'm doing something stupid, but what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `super()` doesn't work as is in Python 2.x. You want to use `super(MyTime, self)` instead.
2. You'll have to override `__new__` instead of `__init__` in this case:

   ```
   class MyTime(datetime.time):
       def __new__(cls, t):
           return datetime.time.__new__(cls, t.hour, t.minute, t.second, t.microsecond)

   print MyTime(datetime.time(10,20,30,400000))
   ```

   prints

   ```
   10:20:30.400000
   ```

Comment: from a theoretic standpoint - when should I override __new__, and when should I override __init__?

Comment: @r0u1i `__new__` when the class you subclass from uses `__new__` for its own initialization, `__init__` if it uses init. I think you have to test; there is no fix rule to this, AFAIK (but it tends to happen more often in C classes...)

Comment: Yep, there's no easy way to tell.  A class can use `__new__` to make two different created objects have the same `id` (by not actually invoking `object.__new__`, and instead returning some existing object), but this will only work right if the underlying data are truly immutable.  (E.g., small `int`s have the same `id`, so that `id(3) == id(3)` is always True, because `int`s are immutable.)  But `datetime.time` objects do not share IDs, I believe, so it's probably just historical accident that they use `__new__`.

Comment: How do we make this solution work with `copy(MyTime(t))`? Currently it throws an error, even if I redefine `__copy__`.